# model.objects.all() doesn't find anything when foreign key in model

Tags: python, django, django-models

[when I load the website i get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCYYS.png)

my models.py file looks like:

```
# Create your models here.
class Information(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    published = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Search(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    searched_titles = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    searched_topics = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_found_articles = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Article_search(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    found_articles = models.ForeignKey(
        Information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    search_details = models.ForeignKey(
        Search, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

in my view.py file:

```
def show_articles_with_this_filter_id(request):
    all = Article_search.objects.all()
    print(all)
    return render(request, 'show_article.html')
```

when I get to the print statement I get the error shown in the picture:
Unknown column 'database_article_search.found_articles_id' in 'field list'

why is the part _id pasted behind found_articles?

this is the error i get when i remove the id from article_search

[id error when printing Article_search.objects.all()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCYr9.png)

Comment: Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to add the column to the table. All ForeignKey fields add an `_id` suffix to the field name for the default column name

Comment: so my Article_search should have -id -found_articles - search_details and found_articles_id? what should be the value of found_articles_id

Comment: `found_articles_id` should be equal to the primary_key of the related `Information` instance

Comment: I thought found_articles is already equal to the primary_key of Information. What am I not seeing correctly?

Comment: `found_articles` is a descriptor that retrieves the related Information instance when accessed, `found_articles_id` is the raw pk value of the related Information. field_name = related instance, field_name_id = raw value in the column

Comment: Ah thanks i didn't know. so you would type something like:     found_articles_id = models.CharField(max_length=200) in the models.py file?

Comment: No, what you have is fine using the ForeignKey. You don't need to define the `_id`, it's implicitly added by the ForeignKey field. You need to create and apply some migrations

Comment: Ah, so when i type the make migrations, and migrate commands there are no migrations to make at all

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create your models here.
class Information(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    published = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Search(models.Model):
    searched_titles = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    searched_topics = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_found_articles = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.searched_titles

class Article_search(models.Model):
    found_articles = models.ForeignKey(
        Information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    search_details = models.ForeignKey(
        Search, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Make model like this and then run two commands
1.python manage.py makemigrations and then 2.python manage.py migrate

```
"In your views.py file"
def show_articles_with_this_filter_id(request,id):
    all = Article_search.objects.filter(id=id)
    print(all)
    return render(request, 'show_article.html')
```

Comment: thank you. So when i try this i get this error: Unknown column 'database_article_search.id' in 'field list'", '42S22'. Almost the same, now the objects.all() tries to find an id field that is not defined

Comment: you have to delete database and migrations as well and then re run those commands..i m 100% sure it will not give any error

Comment: thank you. I have removed all my migrations and models and then run them again. It seems like the migrations makes an id field by default: migrations.CreateModel( name='Article_search', fields=[('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')), . So i still get the id error when i try to get all objects

Comment: send me id error

Comment: you have to filter on the base of the id then u have to get id in your views function and pass it to the URL as well then it will give any error

Comment: I edit my answer please check it

Comment: so i have my mysql connected with the models. I cann't remove the id's in information and Search, because i can than not give a forgeign key in my mysql

Comment: I tried to make the field found_articles the primary key. I than get an error that the field found_articles_id is not found. I see your suggestions are also with the ID fields, still i have no clu how to access this model's data

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ 
please read this

Comment: Yes, i know that page and like it a lot. I understand that every models should have a primary key. Still if I have one I get the error i posted. If I make another field the primary key, models_variable_id doesn't seem to be found for the foreignkeys